# Deserialize nested json objects using Json.Net returns null

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am getting the following nested Json objects from an API I am calling.

```
{"status":"success","data":{"valid_for":3600,"token":"access_token","expires":1123123123123}}
```

The PostResponse class is like below

```
public class PostResponse
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int valid_for { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public int expires { get; set; }
}
```

I get null for postResponse with this code.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
{
     Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
     postResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostResponse>(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: from your sample json: {"status":"success","data":"valid_for":3600,"token":"acces_token","expires":1123123123123}} is not a valid json, you missed { before "valid_for"

Comment: When you do a `ReadToEnd` don't you have to set the read pointer to the start of the stream again in order to make a new `ReadToEnd`, because if so when you try to parse the last `ReadToEnd` will return `""`.

Comment: @dcg Got it.That was the issue.Thanks.

Comment: you miss { just after "data":

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ may help you in the future. Good luck!

Comment: @YoungLearnsToCoding Corrected the json.Actually it was the reader causing the problem since when I was printing it to the console for debugging, the reader is at the end of the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset your stream pointer position, since you already read from a stream when you used `WriteLine` method.

```
Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());

    stream.Position = 0; //Reset position pointer
    reader.DiscardBufferedData();

    postResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PostResponse>(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```